# Timers in web api are destroyed after several hours

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, iis-7.5

i have a web api project that uses unspecified number of timers which is used for task scheduler created by users.
at first, all timers were being destroyed after 20 minutes, then i realized application pool settings were the cause.
these settings are as follow:

1. **Idle Time-out**
2. **Recycling**

even though i have changed Idle Time-out to maximum value(43200 minutes) and Recycling to specific time, still timers are destroyed after 3 or 4 hours.
can anyone help me or suggest a better solution?

Comment: Yes, I have a better solution, use this highly popular project for scheduling: https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: thank you Peter for your solution, but i want to know what is the problem in my project.